# Como passar matriz como parâmetro em C?

Tags: c, funções, matriz, parâmetros

Olá.

Em geral, eu sei que para passar uma matriz como parâmetro de uma função em C, temos que especificar o tamanho das dimensões dela. Mas isso torna a função menos genérica.

Estava pensando em usar a ideia de ponteiro para ponteiro para contornar isso, mas acho que não entendi muito bem como seria possível.

Tentei o código abaixo. Por favor, me indiquem o que está errado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N_LINHAS 3
#define N_COLUNAS 3
void imprime_matriz(int **matriz, int linhas, int colunas){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<linhas;i++){
        for(j=0;j<colunas;j++){
            printf("%d\t",matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i,j,matriz[N_LINHAS][N_COLUNAS];
    for(i=0;i<N_LINHAS;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N_COLUNAS;j++){
            matriz[i][j] = i*j;
        }
    }

    imprime_matriz(matriz,N_LINHAS,N_COLUNAS);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No caso, essa matriz é um ponteiro simples, não um ponteiro de ponteiro. Então, você passa como `*matriz`. Porém, para acessar seus campos, você precisa acessar a matriz sem o "syntax sugar" da variável da função: você precisa calcular o "índice linear" do item da matriz (`matriz[i*colunas + j]` se não me engano)

Answer (score 0):

Seguem as alterações realizadas no código:
inclusão da biblioteca stdlib.h,
inclusão das assinaturas das funções antes do main,
inclusão das variáveis l e c do tipo int que contém o valor das linhas e colunas e a
inclusão da variável **matriz do tipo inteiro sendo um ponteiro de ponteiro

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define linhas 3
#define colunas 3

void ImprimeMatriz(int **matriz, int l, int c);
void LiberaMatriz(int **matriz, int l);

int main()
{
   int **matriz;
   int i,j;
   int l = linhas;
   int c = colunas;

   //Alocando linhas da matriz com malloc

  matriz = (int**)malloc(linhas*sizeof(int*));

  //Alocando colunas da matriz com malloc
  for(i=0;i<colunas;i++){
     matriz[i] = (int*)malloc(colunas*sizeof(int));
  }

 //Inserindo valores na matriz;
 for(i=0;i<linhas;i++){
    for(j=0;j<colunas;j++){
        matriz[i][j] = i+j;
    }
 }

 ImprimeMatriz(matriz, l, c);
 LiberaMatriz(matriz,linhas);

  return 0;
}

//Imprimindo matriz
 void ImprimeMatriz(int **matriz, int l, int c){
   int i,j;
   for(i=0;i<l;i++){
     for(j=0;j<c;j++){
        printf("\t%d",matriz[i][j]);
     }
     printf("\n");
   }
 }


//Como foi alocado um espaço na memória é preciso libera-lo
void LiberaMatriz(int **matriz, int l){
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<l;i++){
    //Liberamos primeiro as linhas
    free(matriz[i]);
  }
  free(matriz);
}
```